# How does a trial version of Software or Antivirus product really work?

Tags: c++, windows, licensing

I want to give my product an offline CRM application to clients which is written in `C++` for a trial period of 30 days. What I am doing at present is give an encrypted file which notes the current date, installation date and some calculations to check this difference if its `>30` - software will not work.

BUT what if client does not change the system date, I mean if he turns off time sync? how can I make my licence to work for trial days?

Will the hours be synced even though date is inactive?

Please let me know.

Answer (score 4):

As with every other security problem, the question isn't whether it's possible to be absolutely secure (because it isn't), but rather, **how secure**.

Even if you can figure out a way to make sure the time is correct, what will prevent the user from removing or tampering with the file? Or uninstalling the trial software, and then reinstall it again? Or decompile it and remove the file check?

BTW, [Beyond Software Architecture](http://amzn.to/1abxVXU) has an overview of various approaches to trial and demo software. Essentially, it answers the original question *How does a trial version of Software or Antivirus product really work?*

Answer (score 3):

You may try saving date and time of the last launch. If you detect that time has been unwound (your last launch was in the future) then you clearly know that user is cheating and  may refuse starting up with an error message.

This, however, should be done carefully. Time should be stored as UTC to avoid all bizzare stuff that happends when daylight saving time kicks in. And detection of time unwinding should have plenty of threshold to give user some freedom in adjusting clock for good reasons.